# php scripts run only after renaming

Tags: php, rename

That's really strange :So after i upload a folder with php files on another service,and try to execute them from a browser,i get 500 error.If i open a file in a text editor,save it with different name like file1.php,then erase the original,and rename the file1.php to the previous name,it works.

Comment: What Webserver do you use? Apache/IIS? Is there anything in the error logs?

Comment: That sounds like a cache issue.  I would see if clearing the browser cache fixes it.

Comment: @fab I use Apache and I found nothing in the error logs about those 500 errors.

Comment: @JOTN clearing cache doesn't help and I don't see how that can be related,because the browser gets 500 responce from the server every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds a lot like a permissions issue.  When you save the "second" file, you're saving it with permissions 0644 by default, with your user/group, at least on *nix.  If you want, post the the output of `ls -l file1 file2` before you do the rename, and I can give you a better answer.

As for permissions, try changing the permissions on the original file by using `chmod`:

```
chmod 0644 <file>
```

Comment: You are ...just prefectly right.Thanks ,and why the scripts didn't work with chmod 0664

Comment: I'm glad it fixed it!  I'm not actually sure why, but it sounds like a possible security feature.  I.e., don't let Apache execute arbitrary scripts that are executable on the system (I.e., /bin/cat).  But that's just a wild guess... :)

Answer (score 2):

The sequence "upload, fail, edit, save, rename, succeed" tells me that it's likely a line-ending issue. Try running:

```
dos2unix original-uploaded-file
```

to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: i thought that it MUST be something like that,but in the first place my developer environment is *nix and the hosting server is *nix and Redmumba was right-it has been a matter of permissions

Comment: But this is definitely one of the steps to take to debug future issues, of course! :)